# How can I update color from an html input type=color

Tags: javascript, html

I'm implementing an interface that allows user to interact with canvas and when pressing on figure that has a previously defined color I'm able to update the input color value by the figure color value but the color on the input button does not change.

In other words, the problem here is that while input [type=color].value is updated, the input color (black by default) does not change according to its value.

I have been checking the updated input value and compare it with selected figure color value, and they match, but I still don't know why the input color does not change.

Here is the html code:

```
<dt>Other</dt>
                  <dd>Filled:
                  <input type="checkbox" style="float:inherit; cursor:pointer" id="Filled"></dd>
                  <dd>Color:
                  <input type="color" style="float:inherit; cursor:pointer"  id="Color"></dd>
```

An here how I'm trying to change the input color and value:

```
document.getElementById("Filled").checked = mySel.filled;
document.getElementById("Color").value = mySel.fill;
```

Where mySel is the selected shape.

Thank you all

Comment: @CyrilBeeckman Sorry for comment styling, first post here.

Comment: @EduFarré it's preferrable for you to edit the question. Not add code in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to update value on input of color type. Note that all you need to do is to update its *value* property, and the color changes automatically.

```js
var colorInput = document.getElementById("testInput");

setInterval( function() {
  if( colorInput.value == "#00ff00") {
    colorInput.value = "#ff0000";
  }
  else {
    colorInput.value = "#00ff00";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<input id="testInput" type="color"/>
```

Comment: I'm doing this but color is still black after changing its value. It matters if new input value is in capital letters or not?